# WinAPI timeBeginPeriod timeEndPeriod usleep

Tags: winapi, sleep

Как правильно использовать эту штуку?
Применяю для повышения точности слипа (и замера времени). Нужно задать период при старте программы, и потом вырубить при выходе?:

```
int main(void){
   timeBeginPeriod(1);
   for(;;){
      ... // много кода
      myUsleep(dt);
   }
   timeEndPeriod(1);
   return 0;
}
```

Или же можно делать так?:

```
int main(void){
   for(;;){
      ... // много кода
      timeBeginPeriod(1);
      myUsleep(dt);
      timeEndPeriod(1);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В [документации написано](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/timeapi/nf-timeapi-timebeginperiod#remarks), что `timeBeginPeriod` следует вызывать непосредственно перед использованием таймера, а `timeEndPeriod` - сразу же после него. Иными словами, рекомендуется чтобы таймер как можно меньше времени работал при повышенном разрешении (это снижает общую производительность системы). А значит вариант `"задать период при старте программы, и потом вырубить при выходе"` лучше не использовать.

Также нужно помнить, что таймер поддерживает только ограниченный диапазон разрешений и этот диапазон у разных компьютеров может отличаться. Поэтому сначала нужно убедиться, что нужное разрешение поддерживается на этом конкретном компьютере, для чего есть функция `timeGetDevCaps`:

```
TIMECAPS tc;
timeGetDevCaps(&tc, sizeof(TIMECAPS));
//если нужное значение не поддерживается - выбираем минимальное из возможных:
UINT period = max(1, tc.wPeriodMin);
```

Comment: Ну я так и делаю (узнавая минимальное возможное значение).
Спасибо за ответ!
(правда, кажется, что эта функция притормаживает работу все программы, если часто вызывать. но, в прочем, это нужно уточнять)